# Multi page VueJS / Express asset issue on production

Tags: express, vue.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a VueJS/Express app to Heroku which consists of two App.vue instances using the '[pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages)' option on vue.config.js.  One for the homepage, and then a seperate Vue app for the Saas app itself. Everything works locally in development, but I'm struggling with the server settings in Express for production on Heroku.

When I go to the page 'app' at [pat-simplebooks.herokuapp.com/app](http://pat-simplebooks.herokuapp.com/app) looking at the sources tab in DevTools the app.js and app.css files returned are both the actual HTML of app.html, hence the app not loading.

[image]

The homepage works fine and is calling the 'index' page as expected.

Here is my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
        entry: 'src/pages/index/main.js',
        template: 'public/index.html',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    app: {
        entry: 'src/pages/app/main.js',
        template: 'public/app.html',
        chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'app']
    }
  }
}
```

And the relevant production settings in Express;

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){

  app.use(history({
    rewrites: [{
        from: /\/app/,
        to: '/app.html'
    }]
  }));

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist')))

}
```

I've tried adding `<base href="/ ">` to the HTML templates, as well as `<base href="/app/" >` but to no avail, as suggested in other answers I've found. Also the `publicPath` webpack option doesn't work for multiple pages as noted in the VueJS docs.

Removing the history redirect setting in Express allows me to navigate to http://pat-simplebooks.herokuapp.com/app.html - which works, however as soon as I refresh the page it redirects back to the 'index' page.

Any help would be great, I've exhausted my Googling skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out, incase anyone has the same issue in future.

The `connect-history-api-fallback` package needed to provided with the `htmlAcceptHeaders` option to only rewrite the html location, and not the JS/CSS assets.

```
app.use(history({

    rewrites: [{
        from: /\/app/,
        to: '/app/index.html'
    }],

    htmlAcceptHeaders: ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml']

}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/dist')))
```